# Why won't my code go through every element in the for loop?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, for-loop

The principle of this sorting algorithm is simple: starting from a float list inlist to be sorted, the elements of inlist will be extracted one at a time, and placed into a new list outlist (originally empty) such that outlist always remain a sorted list.

This algorithm is supposed to go through every element in the list. However, it just stops half way.

```
def insertion_sort(inlist):
  outlist = []
  for i in inlist:
    x = inlist.pop(0)
    outlist.append(x)
  return sorted(outlist)

print(insertion_sort([1,2,6,3,5,4]))
```

The output is [1,2,6] but i want the output to be [1,2,3,4,5,6]
What is wrong with my code?
Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: you are changin the size of `inlist` at every iteration and that explains the output with only 3 elements, that's already not good. But why don't you jut `return sorted(inlist)`

Comment: There's no reason to remove items from `inlist` in the loop. All you're doing is making `outlist` a copy of `inlist` and clearing `inlist` (which has no extra effect here). As @Ivan said, you can just return `sorted(inlist)` to get the same effect.

Comment: "such that outlist always remain a sorted list" It's definitely not doing that now, and you don't need to `pop` from `inlist` to achieve that.

Comment: @Jasmijn what do i replace pop with?

Comment: @SeahJiaHui You're already looping over `inlist`, simply use `i` instead of `x`. You will need to loop over `outlist` as well to figure out where to insert `i`, though, you can't simply `append` it, or it won't be _insertion_ sort.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of insertion sort is below:

```
def insertion_sort(arr):
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        key = arr[i]
  
        # Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
        # greater than key, to one position ahead
        # of their current position
        j = i-1
        while j >=0 and key < arr[j] :
                arr[j+1] = arr[j]
                j -= 1
        arr[j+1] = key
    return arr

arr = [12, 11, 13, 5, 6]
print(insertion_sort(arr))
```

However if you to correct you code then change `for i in inlist:` with  `for i in range(len(inlist)):`
Now this `i` traverse complete inlist, while in you case it is running only half.

Comment: Hmm but i represents the element right? Within the first for loop, wouldn’t arr[i] be arr[12]  and there is no element in the index 12 position?

Comment: No, `i` is running from 1 to 5 `(len(arr) = 5)` so it will not a problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what you want to achieve but try this:

```
def insertion_sort(inlist):
    outlist = []
    for i in range(len(inlist)):
        x = inlist.pop(0)
        outlist.append(x)
    return sorted(outlist)

print(insertion_sort([1,2,6,3,5,4]))
```

Anyway i think the `foreach` cycle dynamically checks the list lengths but with `range-len` you get a fix number on the start of the cycle.